# DJI on-board SDK vs. mini computer

Tags: quadcopter

I am planning to integrate a LIDAR sensor on my DJI Matrice 100 and I will use the data generated to control the height of my UAV. I was wondering if I would need to attach a separate processing unit such as raspberry pi/GPU to process the LIDAR data or would the onboard SDK suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

M100 has a separate power output plug to power the on-board computer, such as Raspberry pi and NUC.

You can use your on-board computer to do the lidar-related computing and send the final control movement command to the M100 sdk serial port.